# Seeking an appropriate antonym to the word Miracle

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, antonyms

> Miracles are rare beneficial events that appear to have a supernatural intervention.

So might not the antonym in one word be *tragedy*?

Of the dozens of other words suggested, *tragedy* for me expresses the most cataclysmic nature of the event:

> **NOT**
>
> *apocalypse*, *catastrophe*, *cataclysm*, *disaster*, *debacle* or *freak incident*,
>
> though the last probably best describes tragedy as an antonym to miracle.

Comment: Both in terms of ***miraculous*** meaning "only possible through divine intervention" and "extraordinary", I suggest the obvious "antonym" is just ***natural***. Which pretty much everything is, so we don't normally need to identify that as an attribute. But even the miraculous parting of the Red Sea was presumably a "tragedy" for those fish left floundering on dry land, so it's not obvious that miracles are always beneficial to everyone, even if we suppose they exist at all.

Comment: I would say that the antonym of a *divine miracle* would be more like a *demonic curse*. (*Curse* is more often the opposite of *blessing*, but there is no exact opposite of *miracle* in this sense.) It really depends what *specific* sense of *miracle* you are trying to negate.

Comment: IMHO, the antonym of “miracle” is “mundane event” (or “routine …”, “ordinary …”, “everyday …”, etc.). While you have indicated (by mentioning “tragedy”, “apocalypse”, “catastrophe”, “cataclysm”, “disaster”, “debacle” and “freak incident”) that you’re focusing on the *beneficial* aspect of “miracle” rather than the *extraordinary* or *supernatural* aspect, you should ***say*** what you’re looking for; don’t just ask for the antonym of a word / definition. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that *miracle* in the sense you describe ("rare beneficial events that appear to have a supernatural intervention") is too complex a concept to have a single antonym. Any feature of this could be negated: what about common beneficial supernatural events? Or rare negative ones?

On the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miracle) site are some example sentences:

1. *the healing miracles described in the gospels*
2. *The bridge is a miracle of engineering.*

The second example is not really what you're talking about, though probably easiest to find an antonym: something along the lines of *ordinary example*.

The first one fits your definition better. But it is really hard to think of an antonym. The main aspect of meaning seems to be the wondrous nature of the event, so again something ordinary or common would form part of a possible antonym. In your question you have focused on examples of negative events -- that doesn't really make it any easier to find anything.

In short, there is no real answer to your question. Antonyms only really apply to a specific group of words -- those which have a fairly simple meaning which lends itself to an opposite (though often antonyms aren't really a real opposite), and it's often easier to find them for adjectives (*big*/*small*, *young*/*old*, etc).

And, if you look at the [Merriam-Webster thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/miracle), it lists a couple of synonyms, but no antonyms at all.